# DataGridView Change cell back color momentarily on change in value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a data source. I would like to have the back color of a cell change (to say red), for 1-2 seconds whenever the value in the cell changes. I have tried and am able to change the cell back color, but am not able to get it back to the default color after a few seconds. The idea is to get the user's attention to the cell whenever its value changes.

Application C# .NET 4.5

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post yoyr code in the question, so we can see what you have tried so far?

Comment: I think you should make your own DataGridViewCell class which has a System.Windows.Form.Timer and handles changes on it's value. When the value changes, reset the timer and change the background color. The timer should change the color back when triggering. Don't have the time to work out a proper solution. Hope this helps anyways.

Comment: Thanks, sbecker....will try that.

Answer (score 1):

I created the example for a button, but you can apply it on your DataGridView cell.

```
    private Color OriginalColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    private int TimeToColorInMiliSeconds = 2000;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorForTwoSeconds(button1);
    }

    private void ColorForTwoSeconds(Button button)
    {
        button.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Task.Run(() => ResetBackColor());
    }

    private void ResetBackColor()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeToColorInMiliSeconds);
        button1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
        {
            button1.BackColor = OriginalColor;
        });   
    }
```

Comment: Thanks KernelMode, i had tried something similar to this, but the problem here is that if the data changes fast, the main thread is practically blocked and the form almost freezes. Any other suggestion?

Comment: If the data changes fast then there are more cases here to handle. For example, what happens if I change the same cell every second. Maybe you should prevent from running the Color logic if the Cell already marked. In addition, AFIK, the Invoke should push the color update task into a queue and the UI thread will do that task when it "free" to do that. Note that the sleep is under different thread. Not the UI. Is it possible that the main thread is blocked on something else?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

if you want to color all the row try this

```
dataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

Much like [KernalMode suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071913/3773066), you can use thread invocation to set the cell's `BackColor` for a period of time. To ensure that additional edits to the cell "reset" the timer on the color change, you can set the cell's tag with the `DateTime` value of its last edit and check against it for time elapsed.

```
private int TimeToColorInMiliSeconds = 2000;

private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Tag = DateTime.Now;
    Task.Run(() => this.ChangeCellBackground(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, Color.White, Color.IndianRed));
}

private void ChangeCellBackground(int col, int row, Color original, Color alert)
{
    this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        this.dataGridView1[col, row].Style.BackColor = alert;
    });

    Thread.Sleep(this.TimeToColorInMiliSeconds);

    this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        DateTime lastChanged = (DateTime)(this.dataGridView1[col, row].Tag);
        DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan elapsed = timeNow - lastChanged;

        if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds >= this.TimeToColorInMiliSeconds)
        {
            this.dataGridView1[col, row].Style.BackColor = original;
        }
    });
}
```

---

**TESTING PURPOSES**

To simulate rapid changes, consider the following example where all cells are initialized to `0` and the click of a button begins a recursive function which increments the value of a cell chosen at random every `N` milliseconds.

```
private int N = 500;
private Random rand = new Random();

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => this.IncrementRandomCell());
}

private void IncrementRandomCell()
{
    int col = this.rand.Next(this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
    int row = this.rand.Next(this.dataGridView1.RowCount);

    this.dataGridView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        int value = int.Parse(this.dataGridView1[col, row].Value.ToString());
        this.dataGridView1[col, row].Value = ++value;
    });

    Thread.Sleep(this.N);
    this.IncrementRandomCell();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. By creating your own cell, you can check if the value changed and handle it accordingly. Using a Forms.Timer avoids using threads.

Since DataGridViewCells don't have OnValueChanged events, we override Paint to check if the value has changed.
If so, we change the BackColor and start the timer to reset the BackColor to it's previous value.

As you can see, I derived from DataGridViewTextBoxCell. But overriding a DataGridViewCheckBoxCell or any other should basically work the same way.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewCustomControls
{
    internal class DataGridViewHighlightChangeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell    
    {
        public Color HighlightColor { get; set; } = Color.Red;
        public int HighlightTime { get; set; } = 1000;

        private object PreviousValue;
        private Color PreviousColor;
        private Timer HighlightTimer = new Timer();

        public DataGridViewHighlightChangeCell()
        {
            HighlightTimer.Tick += HighlightTimer_Tick;
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            HighlightOnChange();

            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        }

        private void HighlightOnChange()
        {
            if (RowIndex == -1 || Value == PreviousValue)
            {
                return;
            }

            PreviousValue = Value;

            if (HighlightTimer.Enabled)
            {
                HighlightTimer.Stop();
                HighlightTimer.Start();
                return;
            }

            PreviousColor = Style.BackColor;
            Style.BackColor = HighlightColor;
            HighlightTimer.Interval = HighlightTime;
            HighlightTimer.Start();
        }

        private void HighlightTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HighlightTimer.Stop();
            Style.BackColor = PreviousColor;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && HighlightTimer != null)
            {
                HighlightTimer.Dispose();
                HighlightTimer = null;
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```